# How to changes value modal attribute in thymeleaf template javascript

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In thymeleaf template, i want to change value of model attribute

IndexController.java

```py
    @GetMapping(value = "/home")
    public String index(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("name", "Red Bean");
        return "/home";
    }
```

index.html

```py
   <h3><span th:text="${name}"></span></h3>
```

I expect value of attribute "name" is "Yellow Bean" use JavaScript

Comment: So..? What's your problem? We need as many details as possible to help you. Also, you are returning a home.html, but you show you are using "name" in index.html. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML="Yellow Bean";`